# StyleTransformer is not run when BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;

Tags: asp.net-mvc, less, bundle

We're using script and style bundles to minify and bundle our resources. We're also using the StyleTransformer to transpile our .less files to .css.

```
coreCsss.Transforms.Add(new StyleTransformer());
coreCss.Include("~/Content/Common/Styles/core.less");
```

We also have a processor directive to only enable optimisations when building a non-debug configuration.

```
#if DEBUG
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
#else
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
#endif
```

The intention of the above is to allow us to more easily debug unpackaged and unminified javascript during development.

The problem we have noticed is that with `EnableOptimizations` disabled, then our .less files are not being transpiled and instead the raw .less is being served to the browser. Is there anyway to disable minification and bundling but still enable transformation? I would guess this is a fairly common scenario.

Answer (score 0):

First, the code you have is completely unnecessary. Out of the box, `EnableOptimizations` is false in development and true in production. The only reason you might need to set it to something is if you actually wanted to enable the bundling in development (where it's disabled by default). That said, bundling is an all or nothing affair, if StyleTransformer depends on the bundling process to function, then if will have to be enabled in development, or you'll get exactly what you have.

Personally, I would recommend using something like the [Web Essentials Visual Studio Extension](http://vswebessentials.com/), which among other things, [will auto-compile LESS into CSS on save](http://vswebessentials.com/features/less). Then, you can work with the LESS, and simply reference the CSS version. I'm sure there's other extensions with similar functionality. You can also set up build tasks to run gulp and such, but that's a little more complex.